# Completing the body of a function in a separate header file in C++?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, vector, stl

I have a homework task where I should complete the body of a function located in a separate file `Find.h` which should be completed in such a way that the code written below should compile successfully:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Find.h"
using namespace std;
class Company {
    std::string name;
    int id;
public:
    std::string getName() const {
        return this->name;
    }

    int getId() const {
        return this->id;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Company& company);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Company& company) {
    return stream >> company.name >> company.id;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Company& company) {
    return stream << company.getName() << " " << company.getId();
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    vector<Company*> companies;
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line) && line != "end") {
        istringstream lineIn(line);

        Company* c = new Company();
        lineIn >> *c;
        companies.push_back(c);
    }

    string searchIdLine;
    getline(cin, searchIdLine);
    int searchId = stoi(searchIdLine);

    Company* companyWithSearchedId = find(companies, searchId);

    if (companyWithSearchedId != nullptr) {
        cout << *companyWithSearchedId << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "[not found]" << endl;
    }

    for (auto companyPtr : companies) {
        delete companyPtr;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is my incomplete attempt for completion of the `Find.h` file (**the program should output the id and the name of the company  that matches the given id**):

```
#ifndef FIND_H
#define FIND_H
#include "Company.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
Company* find(vector<Company*> vc, int id) {

    for (int i = 0; i < vc.size(); i++) {
        if (vc[i]->getId() == id) {
            //I do not know what to write here as to return a pointer 
            //to the required element so as to fulfil the requirement?
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
#endif // !FIND_H
```

Comment: IMHO, you should put the class definition of `Company` into a separate header file, e.g. *company.hpp*, and the method implementations into an associated source file, e.g. *company.cpp*.  Next, tell your compiler or IDE that you have `main.cpp` and `company.cpp` files (how to do this depends on your IDE or build system).

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to define a *functor* or function object and use the `std::find` algorithm:

```
struct Find_By_ID
{
  int id_to_find;
  bool operator==(const Company& a)
  {
    return a->getId() == id_to_find;
  }
}

//...
std::vector<Company> database; // Note, not a vector of pointers
//...
Find_By_ID functor;
functor.id_to_find = searchId;
std::vector<Company>::iterator iter = std::find(database.begin(), database.end(),
                                                functor);
```

**Edit 1:  No `new` necessary**
You don't need to use `new` when building your database:

```
Company c;
std::vector<Company> database;
while (std::cin >> c)
{
  database.push_back(c);
}
```

The `std::vector::push_back()` method will make a copy and append it to the vector.  The vector will allocate memory for the item as necessary.

**Edit 2: Brute force**
You could use a custom brute force method instead of a functor:

```
const std::vector<Company>::const_iterator iter_begin(database.begin());
const std::vector<Company>::const_iterator iter_end(database.end());
std::vector<Company>::const_iterator iter;
for (iter = iter_begin; iter != iter_end; ++iter)
{
  if (iter->getId() == searchId)
  {
     break;
  }
}
if (iter != iter_end)
{
  std::cout << "Customer found by ID.\n";
}
```

If you want to modify the found `Customer`, change the iterator types to:
`std::vector<Customer>::iterator`
as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific issue in the .h file for loop try:

```
return vc[i]; //vc is a vector of Company pointers, this returns the pointer at vc index i
```

For the output part consider:

```
cout << companyWithSearchedId->getId() << " " << companyWithSearchId->getName() << endl;
```

There are more issues here at as a whole, take your time and work through it.